# In Qt Creator, where are the user snippets located in Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, qt, ubuntu, qt-creator, code-snippets

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and QT Creator 2.4.1 and my question is: where are located the user snippet?

I found the original snippets for QT in: **usr/share/qtcreator/snippets**. But the problem is that I need admin permissions.

The **problem** is that I want to export my own snippets in other PC without admin permissions.

Thanks!

Comment: Just to be clear, you are asking for an alternative location QtCreator can be aware of, right? So what is the problem about putting into the home folder and do this as per documentation `To add a new snippet, select Add.`?

Comment: Manuel, is this resolved now?

Comment: Laszlo, it isn't resolved yet. I'll wait to Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. And now, I'm looking for a good snippet system like in Sublime text.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and Qt Creator 2.7.2 and my snippets are located at

```
$HOME/.config/QtProject/qtcreator/snippets/snippets.xml
```

Could be the same for 2.4.1.

Comment: I don't find these file on this folder in my Ubuntu 12.04 and QT Creator 2.4.1. Thanks for your effort.

Comment: Finally, in the new versions of Ubuntu I found it where you pointed out. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the comment, I think the right way is putting this into the home folder. That is also where the snippets get added when you use the "Add" option on the UI.

It is the same location on my Archlinux, Ubuntu 10.04 LTS, Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, and my Debian Wheezy box as well, which is:

```
lpapp ~/.config/QtProject/qtcreator/snippets $ ls
snippets.xml
```

This is not very well documented, but if you take a look at the code, it becomes reasonable after some fiddling:

https://qt.gitorious.org/qt-creator/qt-creator/source/1ed859d39bbe5899b158e1a500b7c8b949a1e201:src/plugins/texteditor/snippets/snippetscollection.cpp#L107

Comment: I don't find these file on this folder in my Ubuntu 12.04 and QT Creator 2.4.1. Thanks for your effort.

Comment: @ManuelIgnacioLópezQuintero: because you have to create it first by using the UI. This is not there by default!

Comment: Laszlo Papp, I don't find the option in the UI, Qt Creator, to create this folder. Sorry for my clumsiness.

Comment: @ManuelIgnacioLópezQuintero: are you sure you have the snippet plugin setup, installed, etc, fine? Could you try a later QtCreator to see if the issue goes away?

Comment: Laszlo Papp, I'm working with Qt Creator right now, so installed a new version is laborious for me. The Snippet plugin is integred and I check this functionality.

Now it's not a problem, but if I want to use another PC I don't know how to export my Snippets.

Comment: @ManuelIgnacioLópezQuintero: copy the folder over, and import it.

Comment: @ManuelIgnacioLópezQuintero: have you resolved it?

Comment: Laszlo Papp, I apologize for the delay. I create this folder and put an snippets.xml with a C++ example in it and it is not working.

I suppose I need to wait until Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.